# Illegal instruction (core dumped) for every installed packages in linux aarch64

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, illegal-instruction

I am using linux aarch64 architecture.
I install miniconda (Miniconda3-py37_4.9.2-Linux-aarch64.sh) in linux.
The steps of installing the miniconda is

`bash Miniconda3-py37_4.9.2-Linux-aarch64.sh`

I provide `/home/su/miniconda3 folder`  to complete installing miniconda3.

Then I create an environment `conda create -n myenv python=3.8`

I checked environment list `conda env list`
It shows

```
base             /home/su/miniconda3
myenv            /home/su/miniconda3/envs/myenv
```

Then I activate the enviroment "myenv" `conda activate myenv` and install tensorflow `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`
Installation has no issue.

But when I import the tensorflow , I got `Illegal instruction (core dumped)`.

I got such kind of Illegal instruction error in numpy, keras, tensorflow packages.

Numpy version is 1.21.5.

kera version is 2.8.0.

tensorflow version is 2.8.2.

Moreover when I check **pip list** in the terminal, I also got Illegal instruction error.

I don't know why I got this error of `Illegal instruction (core dumped)`. May I know how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Comment: @MattDMo, The error that I receive is ```Illegal instruction (core dump).``` when I import the package. While I install packages, there is no error. May I know which part you are not clear?

Comment: So there's no other output than the illegal instruction line?

Comment: @MattDMo, yes I receive only the error message ```Illegal instruction (core dump)``` whenever I import the installed package in aarch64 architecture linux.

Comment: OK, just checking. Does your system already have Python 3 installed? Can you create a virtualenv and install the packages with that?

Comment: When I check ```python3 --version```, it shows Python 3.7.10. Moreover when I type ```python --version```, it shows Python 3.7.10. May I know how can I create virtualenv and install packages with python3? Because I am new to Linux. Furthermore, in my linux I cannot use pip comment also (The issue is I got ```Illegal instruction (core dump)```)and not sure why pip cannot use. May I know is miniconda3 not support pip comment?

Comment: Please follow the instructions mentioned in [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#linux) link to install the tensorflow in your system.